# Ember data find() methods returns array, but I need a single record

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember and Ember-Data.

```
App.InviteRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', { invitation_token: params.token });
  }
});
```

This pings my server and returns a single User record, however the `this.store.find()` method returns an [DS.PromiseArray](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/).

I just need to know how to fetch a single object using Ember-Data using an arbitrary field.

In my template:

```
<h1>This is the invite template.</h1>
<p>{{id}}</p>
<p>{{email}}</p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
App.InviteRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
       return this.store.find('user', { invitation_token: params.token }).then(function(users) {
                  return users.get('firstObject');
        });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, my model is empty when I run this - despite the ajax request firing in the background.

Comment: What does the ajax request return?

Comment: I was using `User.where().first` instead of just `User.where()` on the Rails side - this works perfectly!